# Question about a general linear group

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be the set of all $3\times 3$ nonsingular matrices (over $\Bbb N$ or $\Bbb Z$) i.e., their determinant is non-zero. Then it does not form a group under matrix multiplication. Why?

Comment: elements in the inverse of a matrix of determinant d has denominators typically

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* What is the inverse of the matrix
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix} 2 & & \\ & 2 & \\ & & 2\end{pmatrix}?
$$

Comment: 1/8 times the cofactor matrix.                 Ps: I get your point